# Azure MySQL Flexible Server and private endpoint

Tags: mysql, azure

I have tried to config private endpoint for my Azure MySQL Flexible Server, but the resource is not found [portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBfT1.png). Yes the resource is registered.[image: registered]

If I use Azure Database for MariaDB, I could config private endpoint.

Is the option not available for Azure MySQL Flexible Server? Some note in documentation for Azure MySQL Flexible Server state that you should use other then the small type. I have tried these alternative also, but without any luck!

Any suggestions?

I have tried premium version with General instance, but without any luck. I have tried the same alternati but for MariaDB, no problems to create endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I created MySQL Flexible Server database for in azure portal. I tried to config private endpoint for my server, but I was unable to find my server.

[image]

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-networking-vnet)  you can connect with private access without using private endpoints. while creatin the server enable private access and add the select the vnet subnet and private dns zone directly.
[image]

Otherwise you can use [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-mysql-blog/changing-network-connectivity-options-for-azure-database-for/ba-p/3509233) help to change the connectivity option. In this way I enable private access to my flexible server.

[image]